# Extract string between a word, and a character

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, amazon-redshift

For PostgreSQL.

I have a string that has meta-data inside of it for advertising campaigns.

> Example: `date:20200429-category:phones-audience:youth-promo:nooffer`

I want to be able to extract the value for each key/pair, such as extract phones for a category column, extract youth for an audience column.

**Edit:**
Right now I have it where I do:
`split_part(split_part(example_string_field, 'category:',2),'-',1)`
But it seems a bit messy.

Looking for help, thank you.

Comment: The data is messy. Your solution is fine.

Comment: Redshift or Postgres? Although they share some ancient roots, they are quite different products

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use regular expressions:

```
regexp_substr(str, 'category:([^-])+', 1, 1, 'e')
```

Answer (score 0):

I mostly agree with Bohemian that your solution is fine, but you can pass it through some string manipulation to make it into a key, value table, which makes the final step just a set of selects for single columns. Makes parsing out new columns somewhat easier, just add another line to crosstabbed_data.

```
testdb=# with input_rows as (
select 'date:20200429-category:phones-audience:youth-promo:nooffer' as data
UNION ALL
select 'date:20200430-category:tablet-audience:olds-promo:offer'
),
eav_data as (
SELECT rownum, k_v[1] part, k_v[2] val
FROM
  (
  SELECT rownum, string_to_array(item, ':') AS k_v
  FROM (select rownum, unnest(items) as item from (
    select row_number() over () as rownum, string_to_array(data, '-') as items from input_rows)_0
  )_1 )_2
),
rownums as (select rownum as num from eav_data group by rownum),
crosstabbed_data as (
select
  (select val from eav_data where rownum=num and part='date') as date,
  (select val from eav_data where rownum=num and part='category') as category,
  (select val from eav_data where rownum=num and part='audience') as audience,
  (select val from eav_data where rownum=num and part='promo') as promo
from rownums)
select * from crosstabbed_data;
   date   | category | audience |  promo  
----------+----------+----------+---------
 20200429 | phones   | youth    | nooffer
 20200430 | tablet   | olds     | offer
(2 rows)
```